# Reconstruct stream of many TCP packets into fewer blocks of application data

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

I have a program that is receiving multiple IP packets. To be explicit, the data my program is receiving starts with the source and destination IPs of the packet, then the network header (e.g. TCP, UDP), and finally application data. Some of these packets contain TCP data, whose application data I would like to reconstruct. What is the easiest-to-use C++ library that can do this? I have looked into Netfilter's libipq (deprecated) and libnetfiler_queue, as well as the Epan library that Wireshark uses. These either appear to not do what I require (in the case of the Netfilter libraries), and/or are not documented well enough for me to figure out how I may leverage them correctly (Epan/Wireshark).

Background information: my program is receiving these IP packets from an Android device running VpnService, which forwards encapsulated IP packets from the device. I am receiving them on a server, and forwarding them, through a TUN interface.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't just using a TCP socket?

Comment: Android's VpnService passes the client IP packets, and when they are sent to my server, they are wrapped in another layer of headers. Therefore, I cannot use TCP sockets to receive the original payloads. I also cannot strip the headers from the client data, because then the server could not forward them.

Comment: I don't get it. There is no existing API that can deal with this data flow? I find that very difficult to believe.